# Can I choose which AntD icon to use with allowClear = true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

If I pass `allowClear={true}` to an AntD Input component, a small circle with an × appears at the end of the field once a user has typed something, which can be clicked to empty the contents of the field.

Is there some way to instruct AntD to use a different icon?

The AntD docs for reference: [Input with Clear Icon](https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-allowClear)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For current version `3.19.8` you can't.

The **closest clean [solution](https://iykoh.codesandbox.io/)** will be using `Input.Group` with revealing `clear` button on typing.

[image]

```js
<Input.Group compact>
  <Input
    style={{ width: "80%" }}
    onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    value={value}
  />
  {value && <Button onClick={reset} type="danger" icon="delete" />}
</Input.Group>;
```

> Note: Should add animation on button reveal.

[image: Edit Q-56777640-Input-icon]

Comment: Thank you for the demo!

Comment: I want to change the size of the clear icon in the Autocomplete component any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by passing prop to allowClear:

```
<Input 
 allowClear={{ clearIcon: <CloseOutlined /> }}
/>
```

Comment: Added in 4.x `allowClear: boolean | { clearIcon: ReactNode }`. Versions 3 and lover do not have this unfortunately